# Efficient algorithm to find elements with frequency greater than k in multiple sorted sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

I have a collection of `n` sorted sets. I have to find all the elements with a frequency greater than a given threshold `k`.

I am looking for an efficient algorithm or approach that can handle the case of sorted sets. The algorithm needs to optimize both time and space complexity.

Additionally, performing set operations (such as `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`) is more efficient for my specific use case.

Any suggestions or insights into solving this problem efficiently would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Go and belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. By definition, sets are unsorted and their elements are unique. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: I am using the roaring bitmap (https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/roaring) to create the sets in golang. Roaring bitmap stores elements in sorted order.

Comment: I know in each set elements are unique, but I have n different sets, so they can have common elements.

Comment: If your n sets are already sorted, then you can merge them efficiently into an ordered list. Then pass over it once to find those elements which occur more than k times.

Comment: In fact, you can do both at the same time so you don't have to make copies of the sets.

Comment: I appended all set elements to a list, sorted this list, and iterated over the list to find the result list in linear time. 
But how can I do it without making another list?

Comment: Run n pointers over your n ordered sublists and increment only the one pointing to the lowest value. You can count how many of that value there have been as you go.

Comment: Put a number to the total number of elements.

Comment: If there are `m` elements total, then @Dave's solution is `O(m log(n))`.  Unless `k` is much larger than `n`, I don't think that better is possible.  And even if `k` is much larger, it will be very hard for complex logic to pay for itself.

Comment: @btilly From an earlier OP comment the set elements are unique, so k <= n. If that weren't the case, you could make a slight modification to my approach: after popping an pointer/elt, see how far you could move the pointer before getting to a different elt.

Comment: @btilly if `m` is the total number of elements, in your comment, why can't we just do O(m) (which would be better than your suggested O(m log(n))) by using a map of element to frequency?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I had discounted that because it requires `O(m)` space, and the question asked to optimize both time and space.

Answer (score 0):

Use n pointers. Put your pointers in a min heap based on the value they're pointing at. Have a counter, initially zero. Repeatedly do the following:

- pop the top element off the heap.
- if it is different than the prior top elt (or is the first elt), set the counter to one. If it's the same as the prior elt, increment the counter.
- If the counter is > k, you've found an element that meets your criterion. Add it to a set or list where you're keeping track.
- Increment the pointer associated with the popped elt and add it back to the heap.

Comment: *Use n pointers* or *iterators*, depending on diction for the language you use: references to the *n* sets (and the values therein, one after the other).